# Form validation with Yup (Checkbox) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I've got a from build with mui, [formik](https://formik.org/) and [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup).

If the input fields are empty (f.ex. "surname") after clicking on the submit-button an error shows up. The problem is, that an error **doesn't** show up, if the checkbox isn't checked (Terms of Service).

Here's the relevant code:

```
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  surname: yup.string().required("Surname is missing"),
  termsOfService: yup
    .bool()
    .oneOf([true], "Please accept")
    .required("Please accept"),
});

export default form() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      surname: "",
      termsOfService: false,
    },
    validationSchema: formSchema,
    onSubmit: () => {
      //logic
    },
  });

return (
   <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
   <TextField
         focused
         color="secondary"
         sx={{
             m: 0.5,
             marginBottom: 3,
          }}
          id="surname"
          name="surname"
          label="Vollständiger Vorname"
          value={formik.values.surname}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          error={formik.touched.surname && Boolean(formik.errors.surname)}
              />
   <div>
     <Checkbox
         {...label}
         color="secondary"
         sx={{ color: "#9E3FB0", marginLeft: "-6px" }}
         id="termsOfService"
         name="termsOfService"
         label="termsOfService"
         value={formik.values.termsOfService}
         onChange={formik.handleChange}
         error={
             formik.touched.termsOfService &&
             Boolean(formik.errors.termsOfService)
          }
         helperText={
             formik.touched.termsOfService &&
             Boolean(formik.errors.termsOfService)
          }
       />
       <p className={styles.pNoteAGB}>Accept.</p>
   </div>
   <ButtonDefault text="Analyse starten" type="submit" />
   </form>
) 
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Hello! Do you have perhaps some minimal reproducible sample for this issue? Like codesandbox?

Comment: Hello. Here's a minimal reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-poincare-i5qsyd. Hope this is enough?

Comment: You want text error to appear and change border of checkbox to red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Checkbox` doesn't have `error` field of its own like `TextField`. You need to use `FormControl` and `FormHelperText` to achieve that. I have added updated code below. and also added `FormControlLabel`. Let me know if you require further changes in it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import {
  TextField,
  Checkbox,
  Button,
  Alert,
  FormHelperText,
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel
} from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  surname: yup.string().required("Missing surname!"),
  termsOfService: yup
    .bool()
    .oneOf([true], "Please accept.")
    .required("Please accept.")
});

export default function App() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      surname: "",
      termsOfService: false
    },
    validationSchema: formSchema,
    validateOnChange:false,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setAlert("success");
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {}, [alert]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {alert === "success" && <Alert severity="success">Success!</Alert>}
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <TextField
            focused
            color="secondary"
            sx={{
              m: 0.5,
              marginBottom: 3
            }}
            id="surname"
            name="surname"
            label="Surname"
            value={formik.values.surname}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            error={!!formik.errors.surname}
            helperText={formik.errors.surname ?? " "}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
        >
          <FormControl error={!!formik.errors.termsOfService}>
            <FormControlLabel
              label="Accept."
              id="termsOfService"
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  color="secondary"
                  sx={{
                    color: `${
                      !!formik.errors.termsOfService ? "error.main" : "#9E3FB0"
                    }`,
                    marginLeft: "-6px"
                  }}
                  name="termsOfService"
                  value={formik.values.termsOfService}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                />
              }
            />
            <FormHelperText>
              {formik.errors.termsOfService ?? " "}
            </FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
          Start Analysis
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's only one thing left: as soon as I enter the surname, the error from terms of service appears. But it should show up after clicking on the submit button. Can you tell me how to handle this?

Comment: I have added `validateOnChange : false,` inside `useFormik` Please check.